# 80004005 Error with VBScript that works

Tags: vbscript

For some reason, I have one network drive that does not connect until I access it by shortcut. So I added a run command to a startup script for launching my email and IM apps. The script works, but I keep getting Error 80004005.

```
Dim WshShell, objShell, oShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Check for network connection
strURL = "server1"

set png = WshShell.exec("ping -n 1 " & strURL)
do until png.status = 1
    WScript.Sleep 5000
loop
strPing = lcase(png.stdout.readall)
Select Case True
     Case InStr(strPing, "reply from") > 1 

'Launch Chrome
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""")

'Launch Pidgin
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe""")

'Initiate Y:\
    objShell.Run("C:\Users\kwag.myers\Documents\Y.lnk") 'this line errors
    Wscript.Sleep 500

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    oShell.AppActivate "Y:\"
    Wscript.Sleep 500
    WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"

Case Else
End Select 
Set WshShell = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: You get that error on which line?

Comment: What user context is the script running in?  I'm thinking this could be a permissions issue.

Comment: eurotrash, line 23: objShell.Run("C:\Users\kwag.myers\Documents\Y.lnk") 'this line errors.

Comment: Comintem, I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I have admin access, but not logging in as admin.

Comment: Comintem, I took a look at some of the folder permissions and noticed Y:/ had some Special settings. As I descended into the directory these Special permissions were not listed. So, I set the Y.lnk properties a couple layers deeper (and matched the closing AppActivate directory) and no more error. Thanks!!!